# Using a MAX aggregate in an Entity Framework/LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, aggregate-functions, ef-core-7.0

I have a project where I need to use Entity Framework Core 7 against a MSSQL database but I'm stuck in bringing the MAX aggregate in SQL as a part of the LINQ statement.

Consider the following data:

```
Create Table #Member (
    MemberID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    FirstName VarChar(20)
)

Create Table #QuestLog (
    QuestID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    MemberID int,
    Quest VarChar(20),
    GoldCollected Int,
    MonstersDispatched Int
)
```

This is the data for those tables:

```
Insert #Member(FirstName) Values('Wealda')
Insert #Member(FirstName) Values('Tunbin')
Insert #Member(FirstName) Values('Ealhart')
Insert #Member(FirstName) Values('Rancent')

Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, '1000 Doors', 100, 6)
Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, '1000 Doors', 50, 100)
Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, '1000 Doors', 75, 2)
Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, 'Rats!', 555, 1500)
Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, 'Kill Dr. Lucky', 50, 0)
Insert #QuestLog(MemberID, Quest, GoldCollected, MonstersDispatched) Values(1, 'Kill Dr. Lucky', 1000, 1)
```

Here is the SQL query that brings me the data I want.

```
Select M.FirstName, Q.Quest, Max(Q.GoldCollected) MaxGold
From #Member M
    Inner Join #QuestLog Q
        On M.MemberID = Q.MemberID
Group By M.FirstName, Q.Quest
```

Which gives me this dataset:

| FirstName | Quest | MaxGold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wealda | 1000 Doors | 100 |
| Wealda | Kill Dr. Lucky | 1000 |
| Wealda | Rats! | 555 |

This is what I have so far in the LINQ query.

```
var query = from m in dbContext.Member
                join q in dbContext.Quest on m.MemberID equals q.MemberID
            group new { m, q} by new { m.FirstName, q.Quest } into g 
            select new { FirstName = m.FirstName, Quest = q.Quest, MaxGold = ??? };
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I translate the aggregate Max into a LINQ query and get the dame results?

Comment: It will be much simpler if you'd use a [navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#collection-navigations) `Member.QuestLogs` instead of joining + grouping. Please try that.

Comment: @GertArnold Unfortunately, the actual data structures I'm working with (not the member/quest contrivance I built for demo the problem space) doesn't have any established FK relationships between the tables and asking for one is not going to get me anywhere. The joys of legacy systems. With that in mind, do I have to go change the models to add those navigators by hand? :(

Comment: If that is how the tables are connected *de facto*, yes, I'd surely do that. It's a one-time investment that exempts you from writing joins all the time, again and again, and will reduce complexity and coding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, it is trivial grouping query:

```cs
var query = 
    from m in dbContext.Member
    join q in dbContext.Quest on m.MemberID equals q.MemberID
    group q by new { m.FirstName, q.Quest } into g 
    select new 
    { 
        FirstName = g.Key.FirstName, 
        Quest = g.Key.Quest, 
        MaxGold = g.Max(x => x.GoldCollected) 
    };
```

Comment: If no navigation property is used (even though that's highly recommended) it's better to use a GroupJoin.

Comment: @GertArnold, Why it is better? `GroupJoin` has no direct SQL representation and usually it generates subquery. Later when you need two aggregates, you will throw GroupJoin and rewrite to grouping.

Comment: More concise (and less error-prone) code is also worth something and it *is* translated into SQL that does the job. A subquery isn't necessarily a bad thing. Using navigation properties don't have a SQL representation either (if that means that the LINQ query doesn't look like the SQL query), IMO that doesn't means they're bad either.

Comment: I mean, if you use operators which has no direct SQL translation - you expects that EF Core is good in emulation, which is not always true. Single entity navigation properties has direct translation with JOIN. Probably you have missed that OP cannot create navigation properties which you expect.